# Annihilator of any semisimple module over an algebra and Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove the annihilator $\operatorname{Ann}_{R}M$ of any semisimple module ${}_{R}M$ over the algebra $R$ contains the Jacobson radical $J(R)$.

Comment: Just for your future reference, the word is annihilator (Latin nihil="nothing", Latin annulus=“ring”)

Comment: @Lubin, sorry, I'm not a native speaker. Next time I'll double check my grammar)

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask questions. You're going to get negative attention otherwise.

Comment: @Lubin I don't think “annihilator” has anything to do with “annulus”. It comes from a late Latin *annihilatus*, reduced to nothing. In Italian we have *annichilito* which has the same origin.

Comment: @egreg, of course it doesn’t. That’s exactly what I said. OP’s original spelling was “annulator”, now corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This holds for any ring, not necessarily commutative.

A semisimple (left) $R$-module is the sum of simple submodules: say $M=\sum_{\lambda}S_\lambda$, with $S_\lambda$ simple. If $r\in R$ and $rM=0$, then $rS_\lambda=0$, for every $\lambda$. Conversely, if $rS_\lambda=0$ for every $\lambda$, also $rM=0$. Therefore
$$
\operatorname{Ann}_RM=\bigcap_\lambda \operatorname{Ann}_RS_\lambda
$$
Hence the result follows if you show that, for every simple module $S$,
$$
J(R)\subseteq\operatorname{Ann}_RS
$$
Now
$$
\operatorname{Ann}_RS=\bigcap_{x\in S}\operatorname{Ann}_Rx
$$
If $x=0$, then $\operatorname{Ann}_Rx=R$; if $x\ne0$, then $\operatorname{Ann}_Rx$ is a maximal left ideal of $R$. Indeed
$$
Rx\cong R/\!\operatorname{Ann}_Rx
$$
and maximality follows from the fact that $Rx=S$ is simple.

Since $J(R)$ is the intersection of all maximal left ideals, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hints (and sub-hints)

1. Let $M$ be a $R$-module. Prove that $M$ is *simple* if and only if $M\simeq R/\mathfrak{m}$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subset R$. Subhints for proving the above:

   - Suppose $M$ is simple. Fix $0\neq m\in M$, and consider the map  $\varphi_m:R\to M$ given by $r\mapsto rm$. Prove that $\varphi_m$ is surjective. Let $\mathfrak{m}=\ker \varphi_m$. Prove that $\varphi_m$ induces an isomorphism  $\varphi'_m: R/\mathfrak{m}\to M$.
   - Let $I\subset R$ be an ideal of $R$. Prove that $R/I$ is simple if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal.
2. Let $\{M_\alpha\}$ be a family of $R$-modules. Prove that $\mathrm{Ann}\left(\bigoplus_\alpha M_\alpha\right)\subset \bigcap_{\alpha}\mathrm{Ann}(M_\alpha)$.

Use these two to prove what you want.